# Constraint qualification holds iff...

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let's say we have an optimization problem.

Are the following equivalences true?

(a) A constrained qualification holds $\Leftrightarrow$ 
(b) strong duality holds $\Leftrightarrow$ (c) $\lambda_0 > 0$, where $\lambda_0$ is from [Fritz John conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_John_conditions) $\Leftrightarrow$ (d) KKT conditions become necessary

Comment: I guess it is correct, except for (b). It should have been: (b) strong duality holds, if convex problem

Comment: In fact, (b) should have been: (b) strong duality holds, if convex problem and the constraint qualification is Slater condition

Comment: You should state this better. Constraint qualifications are conditions for any type of optimization described by equality and inequality (and maybe with abstract convex sets included), not only convex problems.